# stuck with group by script

Tags: mysql, sql

a.  Create a stored procedure called spMaxInventoryByType.

The stored procedure will use the view called vInventoryByType.

It will display the highest inventory level value within each product subtype, recorded during the month of the year supplied by the input parameters.

Each row returned by the procedure will list the product type name, the product subtype name and the highest inventory level value recorded out of all products within that product subtype, during the specified reporting period.

I cant figure out why the guy has Used GROUP BY for ProductTypename & ProductSubtypeName for this procedure?

any insights?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spMaxInventoryByType @YEAR INT, @MONTH INT AS
SELECT ProductTypeName
     , ProductSubtypeName
     , MAX(InventoryLevel) "Max Inventory Value"
  FROM vInventoryByType
 WHERE DATEPART(mm FROM DateOfInventory)=@MONTH 
   AND DATEPART(yyyy FROM DateOfInventory)=@YEAR
 GROUP 
    BY ProductTypeName
     , ProductSubtypeName
```

Comment: Probably wants to get max inventory level per type and subtype? Rationale is impossible to explain just based on the query itself.

Comment: does it help now?

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: This is not MySQL code.  You should tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

When you're grouping the results of a query (in this case, to get the MAX inventory level for each subtype), you need to include at least all the fields that were used in the SELECT clause out of the MAX function in the GROUP BY clause, so that each group of (type-subtype) has only one MAX value.